# Можно ли передавать класс как аргумент функции

Tags: c#, функции, smtp

Хочу написать функцию которая отправляет сообщение на почту, но можно ли написать логин, пароль, сервер и т.д. в отдельном классе? Я попытался это сделать, но не могу понять как сделать так чтобы весь класс был аргументом.

Вот сама функция:

```
public int Send(AccountClass account, string emailAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        string res;
        MailAddress from;
        MailAddress to;
        MailMessage message;
        try
        {
            from = new MailAddress(account.login, ((String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(account.Name)) ? account.login : account.Name));
            to = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
            message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(account.smtpServer);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(account.login, account.password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = account.enableSsl;

            smtp.Send(message);
            res  = "OK";
         }

         catch
         {
            res = "not OK"
         }
         return res;
```

в этой функции первый аргумент, вот его класс:

```
public class AccountClass
{

    public string login = "/*--*/";
    public string Name = "proverka";
    public string smtpServer = "/*--*/";
    public string password = "/*--*/";
    public bool enableSsl = false;
}
```

так вот, как при вызове этой функции передавать весь AccountClass?

Comment: Что значит весь? Вы не можете передать часть класса.

Comment: ну так `new AccountClass`;

Comment: Вот как вы написали, так и передавайте. Создаете новый экземпляр класса, наполняете и передаете. Или возникают какие то загвоздки?

Comment: Так?
`AccountClass ac = new AccountClass();`
`Send(ac, ...);`

Comment: @MiT да, я так делал, но до меня не дошло что надо объявлять экземпляр класса в методе, где использую функцию. спасибо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как написали, так и передавайте. Рекомендую использовать `System.Security.SecureString` для хранения пароля